# How can I reload the entire page when only the url hash changes?

Tags: javascript

How do I reload a page if the only change to the url is a hash? `location.href` doesn't work as I expect.

```
location.href= siteUrl + '#T_blockName';
```

This doesn't refresh the page unless I change `siteUrl`. How is it possible?

Comment: You want a full, standard refresh when the hash fragment changes?

Comment: How about CURRENT_SITE_URL + "?" + (new Date().valueOf()) + '#T_blockName'

Comment: i am not sure. it can be problem with mod_rewrite

Comment: yes, solved by location.reload
location.hash = hash;  location.reload(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible because simply changing the hash part isn't going to request a page reload since hash is usually considered to be part of the page (anchor, id etc.).

You need to specifically request a page reload but how you are going to do it depends on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `location.hash`. This *retrieves* the hash. To change it, you need to use an anchor or set `window.location` to the location plus the hash you want.

Also, you are using PHP concatenation syntax when you should be using `+`.

Comment: This still won't refresh the page will it?

Comment: No. I am not sure what the OP wants. I added another clarification in my answer.

Comment: becasue of too much concentration on php at the moment, i missed concatenation syntax :))

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you concatenate strings in javascript, you need to use `+` instead of `.`.

```
location.href= CURRENT_SITE_URL + '#T_blockName';
```